# Salesforce validation

Tags: lookup, validation, validation-rule

I have a validation rule which check's field value (lookup) is "study" then it validates child object field DATE Should be within 90 days from today
below is the validation rule

```
IF($ObjectType.Project__c.Fields.Status__c ='Study' && Date__c <= TODAY()+90 ,TRUE,FALSE)
```

But it's not working. Why?

Comment: Hi Alex, please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. You should really be more specific than "not working" whenever possible. Does it fail to compile? Are you getting an error message? Also note, for `Boolean` values you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`. They're the same.

Answer (score 3):

The `$ObjectType` notation is for accessing the Schema level information about a Field (such as api name, label etc.), and not the values of that field within a record? I think you have perhaps confused this with using a lookup.

From the information you have provided I would imagine you are after something more like:

```
IF(Project__r.Status__c ='Study' && Date__c <= TODAY() + 90, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
Project__r.Status__c ='Study' && Date__c <= TODAY() + 90
```

This assumes the lookup is called "Project__c" (though note the use of the 'r' to navigate the relationship).